# Command for taking a screenshot to a new file

Tags: shell-script, files, filenames

I want to configure a global hotkey to take a new screenshot and save it, say, somewhere inside my home folder. I can take a screenshot with ImageMagick with this command:

```
import screenshot.jpg
```

However, if I execute this multiple times, screenshot.jpg will be overwritten multiple times. I want the application to write screenshot1.jpg, screenshot2.jpg, etc. automatically. What my command would look like in this case?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include a command line method that shows you how to do the filename the way you were looking for. LMK if you need additional guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the file as

```
import screenshot-`date +%H%M%S`.jpg
```

Comment: You probably want to include date as well. :)

Comment: Nice solution. One question appears: `import \`date +"%d_%b_%T"\`.jpg` runs well, but when I replace underscores with spaces, filename formats only as `%T` and the rest (`%d %b`) causes import to run incorrectly. Any clues on how can I run `date +"%d %b %T"` in one expression inside the import command?

Comment: See man pages of `date` command. If that upsets you then go for `sed` to replace underscore by space

Answer (score 4):

#### GUI Method

You can also use a tool such as [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) to do this. It provides the ability to take screenshots of selections, windows, or the entire desktop. These actions can be customized to a specific keyboard shortcut within Shutter.

*dialog showing keyboard mappings*

[image: ss of shutter 1]

*dialog showing naming pattern*

[image: ss of shutter 2]

#### Commandline Method

If you use the command [`import`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) which is part of the [ImageMagick toolset](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

#### Example

You simply run the command below and then click the left mouse button when you're ready to take a screenshot.

```
$ import "screenshot-$(date  +"%d %b %T").jpg"
```

Resulting in this file:

```
$ ls -l | grep screenshot
-rw-rw-r--   1 saml saml  2273538 Sep 26 13:06 screenshot-26 Sep 13:06:55.jpg
```

With this form of the command you have to quote any arguments to `import` so that the filename doesn't get split on spaces.

```
$ import "...file with spaces..."
```

You can also use this command to take a screenshot of the currently active window:

```
$ import -window \
    "$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window" | cut -d" " -f5)" \
    "screenshot-$(date  +"%d %b %T").jpg"
```

In the above example, the `xprop` command will programmatically determine the active window's ID:

```
$ xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window" | cut -d" " -f5
0x2e00004
```

There are more elaborate things you can do here, this is just to whet your appetite.

Answer (score 2):

A script:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
maxn=1000
bn=screenshot%.jpg

while [[ $n -lt $maxn ]]; do
    # create temporary filename
    tn=${bn/\%/${n}}
    # check whether the file already exists
    if [[ -f $tn ]]; then
        ((n++))
    else
        screenshot_command $tn
        break
    fi
done
```

`$bn` is file base name in which the percent character acts as a placeholder for a number. Note that if yo remove some of the files, they will be recreated since the name will be used once the file doesn't exist - you can revert the order of counting (i.e. decrement from maximum) and use last non-existing filename once you hit one that already is there.