# Screenshot tool Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, screenshot

In Linux Mint (15) you have a screenshot tool, 'described' [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/85)

You read

> More difficult way
>
> But sometimes - mostly in games - this shortcut doesn't work. What to do then? >You can use Take Screenshot application to make a screenshot after a delay.
>
> To start Take Screenshot application: Mint Menu -> All applications -> >Accessories -> Take Screenshot.
>
> Next select Grab the current window, disable Include pointer option, disable >Include window border, and choose Effect: None.
>
> Now it's time to choose the delay. I usually choose 10-15 seconds. Why? Because >it's the time period in which you have to launch the application (mostly game) and start playing.
>
> After you've chosen the delay click the Take Screenshot button, and then >quickly launch the game, start playing, and wait until Save Screenshot window appears.

What is the name of this program, (and not Screenshot but a name so I can actually google it)?

I want to know it because I'm searching for an alternate on windows, not really necessarily but if anyone knows one, that answers my question too (which at least has the `Select area to grab` function).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command for taking a screenshot to a new file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/command-for-taking-a-screenshot-to-a-new-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `gnome-screenshot` and it is part of Gnome, not specific to Mint. There is also `xfce4-screenshooter` which is very similar. As a general rule, you can find the name of a program launched by a menu shortcut by either right clicking on it or going into the menu settings and finding the relevant entry.

If for whatever reason you cannot find it that way, you can always

1. make a list of currently running processes:

   ```
   ps aux | sort > a
   ```
2. Run the program in question and, while it is running, get a list of the processes again:

   ```
   ps aux | sort > b
   ```
3. Compare the two lists of processes to find the new one:

   ```
   diff a  b
   ```